# I can't get my JavaScript Function to work in Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I am having Trouble getting my JavaScript function to work in Internet explorer. It works in all browsers other then explorer.

The user clicks on a button, which calls a function that checks to see if the password is correct. If its correct it takes the user to "members only page" if it is incorrect it tells the user that the password is incorrect

```
<script>
    function myFunction2() {
        if (PasswordTextbox2.value == "!2008Buzzer1") {
            location.href = '/JnHSDHdM3gDOEffDUt68HJHU.aspx'
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ErrorLocation").innerHTML = "Your Password is incorrect";
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="text" name="PasswordTextbox2" id="PasswordTextbox2">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value='Submit'>
<p style="color: red" id="ErrorLocation"></p>
```

Comment: Are u sure this code is working on other browsers? because it seems You cannot directly use html controls in JavaScript side,
You must use document.getElementById('controlId') or in jQuery like $('controlid').

Comment: use `document.getElementsByName('PasswordTextbox2')[0].value);`, this should solve the issue you are having.

Comment: @MunavvarHusein actually his code works in Chrome just fine, as I just tested it

Comment: Thanks, What is the entire block of code that I should use

Comment: Do you realize that putting a password check in your javascript means it is very easily bypassed?

Comment: @MunavvarHusein - abc123 - This is part of the HTML5 Spec see http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object for reference. It is probably a terrible idea, but modern browsers will create global variables on the window object for named inputs. This could be why it works in chrome but not explorer... I would say that abc123 's solution should make it work in legacy browsers

Comment: @abc123 Can you tell me the full code block that I should use. I'm not sure where to put your line

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid referencing elements by their name / ID directly, it's a non-standard feature.

Instead use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), and the other `.get*`, & `.query*` methods exclusively.

You should also know that storing a password in JavaScript offers no real security. This JavaScript runs on the client's machine - anyone who has access to your page can see this password.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var password = document.getElementById('PasswordTextbox2'),
      error = document.getElementById("ErrorLocation");
  if (password.value == "!2008Buzzer1") {
    location.href = '/JnHSDHdM3gDOEffDUt68HJHU.aspx';
  } else {
    error.innerHTML = "Your Password is incorrect";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="PasswordTextbox2" id="PasswordTextbox2">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value='Submit'>
<p style="color: red" id="ErrorLocation"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks OKA, but I need the location.href = '/JnHSDHdM3gDOEffDUt68HJHU.aspx'; it must redirect users to that page if they enter the correct password

Comment: [`//` indicates a comment in the code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Comments). You can just remove the leading `//`, but I've also updated my answer.

Comment: Is there a way for me to have the password hidden in the source code

Comment: Nope. You can obfuscate it through various means, but it will still be visible in some way.

Comment: @RossYellin you need to use OAuth to with SSL for initial login then use Auth Token